# Integration task for the 2 apps

Tags: java, android, spring, spring-integration

I get a task for the merging code for the 2 apps and creating a new end point. The project structure looks,

[image]

The flow diagram is like,

[image]

I have experience with Java, Spring RESTful, and JAX-RS. Where can I get started? Some suggestion of the docs will be helpful.

Comment: I think you are a bit early on to come here yet. First maybe look at Spring Integration if you want to go down an integration path, other one is Camel but since you are already using Spring.. Otherwise you may want to use a BPM such as activiti.

Comment: @Snickers3192 If the question sounds too naive, then perhaps it is that. I have no idea on the matter, I guess `Spring-integration` will be easy as I have little experience on that

Comment: @Snickers3192  could you please direct me to a project example where common end-point was created after merging different parts of the software? I'm not your code, some open source example project to use for the learning etc

Comment: Do you just want to make a proxy? Keep the projects same as is? Your not very clear because you are giving a process diagram which seems like you want to do integration, but the you sort of say you want to just have 1 project instead of two? And then you say in a comment you want one end point, which you could do just by creating a proxy.

Comment: I am not clear because I not sure what to ask for, so, may write a little to educate and provide brief overview then :)   Anyway, I need a common endpoint from the apps, so I guess it will be creating a proxy.  Do you have any code sample on how to do so? I'm also looking at the Spring integration ref docs, but thats yugeee

Comment: If you just need a proxy, you can use a pre-built thing like nginx, or if you want something simple, just look at Spring Cloud Zuul.

Comment: Could you please write an answer to different possibilities? We will eventually need to deploy to the AWS, so, need to consider that for writing the code